# "No emulator installed" error in Android Studio even though Intel HAXM is up and running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

Complete newbie, fresh Android Studio install, trying to run an emulator ends up coughing a "[No emulator installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFPbh.png)" error. Clicking the *Install Emulator* link does nothing. Trouble is, I've gone through tens of how-to articles and StackOverflow questions and did everything mentioned in those, to no avail.

What I have:

- Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3
- CPU: i7, supports HAXM
- BIOS: "Virtualization" under Advanced tab is Enabled. It doesn't mention Intel or "Vt-x" or anything like that, just "Virtualization", but I guess that's it
- Windows' Hyper-V is disabled
- I enabled anything that mentions *Google API*, *Emulator*, or *Intel* in the SDK Manager. Here is how it looks on the SDK Platforms, SDK Tools and SDK Update Sites tabs: [image: SDK Platforms] [image: SDK Tools] [image: SDK Update Sites]
- I installed Intel HAXM manually, via its downloaded installer.
- In the Terminal, if it type `...\sdk\tools>emulator-check accel`, it says:

`accel: 0 HAXM version 6.2.1 (4) is installed and usable. accel`

- If I type `sc query intelhaxm`, I get:

`SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First time I have met that problem I resolved it by uninstalling and removing all traces of Android Studio and installing it again. Next time when the same problem occurred on another machine I have found easier way to solve the problem:

1. Go to Android SDK location and remove "emulator" and "system-images"
   directories. The default path to SDK is "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
2. In the Android Studio launch SDK manager, go to
   "Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK" menu, select "SDK
   Tools" tab and check "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM
   installer)" and "Android Emulator" checkboxes and click apply. Some
   download and setup actions should occur at that point
3. Go to AVD manager, delete all AVDs and create new AVD you need.

The Emulator started successfully after that.

Comment: post an update in May2020, I encountered this same error, even though I had HAXM installed. So, in SDK TOOLs, i unchecked Android Emulator & HAXM... then i restarted my comp.. and then went back to AS and checked both of them. This made them re install and everything worked! ;-)

Comment: uncheck emulator in sdk tools apply, this will unstall emulator, then check it again and appy this will install it again, it seems as if it is not configured correctly so avd is unable to use it. this worked for me

Answer (score 15):

Hi simply go to your SDK then SDK tools and click to Uncheck Android emulator to uninstall it , then download and reinstall through SDK tools Android emulator. This work for me

I hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Worked for me, there was no need for scorched earth and reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by removing /emulator folder and re-installing via sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Linux with i7 processor and 32GB or RAM. This was a reinstall of the Linux OS and it had worked fine before. What I discovered was that the emulator doesn't like my video card, and setting the Hardware Acceleration to Auto caused it to select hardware and crash! Manually setting Hardware Acceleration to Software solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "**Control Panel\System and Security\System**" and open your Device Manager. Once Device Manager opens, go to Display Adapters and select the name of your graphics driver. Select the "Driver" tab, then click "Update Driver". This completely fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

goto this location "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

If you have any folder like emulator.anythung, just rename it to just 'emulator'

That is how i fixed mine.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the path to follow :

1. goto this location "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
2. delete emulator folder.
3. then go setting in android studio
4. chick android sdk
5. sdk tools
6. select sdk emulator and apply

emulotor will be installed.